# Ubuntu 14.04 Elantech touchpad too sensitive

Tags: touchpad

I am using samsung series 3 laptop. I recently shifted from Windows 8 to (my touch works just fine on Windows 8).After writing 2-3 words the focus shifts to where the cursor lies.  I tried some resolutions suggested on the web but could not resolve the problem.(I want to fix it without buying an external mouse, which is of course a solution). The touchpad is ETPS/2 Elantech as detected in Terminal by xinput.

Right now Synaptic finger is set to 1 1 0 . I tried changing it to 50 90 255 as suggested somewhere on web but it freezes the mouse in that case.

Comment: I had a similar problem with mouse sensitivity and my problem was solved by python script. See [HERE](http://askubuntu.com/questions/808009/mouse-deceleration-set-how-to).

Answer (score 0):

You probably solved your problem, but I'm posting for posterity's sake: changing the Synaptic Finger setting to 5 16 216 solved it for me.

Comment: These numbers improved things for me, but didn't solve things entirely - where did you get them from? What do you think they mean?

Answer (score 0):

Edit `50-synaptics.conf` file:

```
sudo nano /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf
```

Add the following line:

```
MatchIsTouchpad "on"
Option "TapButton1" "1"
```

Like this:

```
Section "InputClass"

Identifier "touchpad catchall"
Driver "synaptics"
MatchIsTouchpad "on"
Option "TapButton1" "1"
Option "VertEdgeScroll" "1"
```

Save, exit and reboot.